# Get Coordinates of a Table Cell in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, grid, coordinates

I am working on a maze generating algorithm visualisation in JavaScript, I made a 5x5 grid but now I require that whenever i click a table cell(), I get its coordinates i.e in which row it is and in which column. How would I go about implementing this?

Here's what im doing right now:

```
cell.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this)
    }
```

Here's how Im generating the cells and rows:

```
for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
let row = grid.insertRow();

for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    let cell = row.insertCell()
}}
```

Edit: I played around with the code and implemented MauriceNino's solution.

Here's the code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let row = grid.insertRow();

    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        let cell = row.insertCell()
        cell.row = i
        cell.column = j

        cell.onclick = function(evt) {
            console.log(cell.row + 1)
            console.log(cell.column + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calculating that would be a pain to do, I would rather set the needed parameters (column and row) during the generation of those cells.

Comment: I updated how I'm generating the grid, would your solution be viable in a situation like this? I will implement a cell class later on for working with the algorithm

Comment: What is this grid class?

but yeah if that works, its a fine solution

Comment: @MauriceNino I implemented your solution, it works now. Thanks!